# MongoDB, which is faster: find.limit(10) or aggregate({$limit:10})

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I know which is faster and more efficient, `find.limit(10)` or `aggregate({$limit:10})`? I heard a lot that limit affects Mongo's performance, is that true, or this has changed since the new 3.0 engine.

Also, is there a practical way to evaluate performance of queries on mongo?

Comment: Technically the big engine changes were implemented in the 2.6 release, and the 3.0 being more of a point that a pluggable storage alterate was made available, but all the real changes were already there. Not really any difference between the two, but it depends on what you are doing. The big "misnomer" here is that `.aggregate()` is slow, which it is not. Aggregation operations that people want to do are intrinsically "slower" than a general query that does not do those things. If you want "practical" I would suggest timing comparisons, but again it's all about what you are actually doing.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, How to do timing comparison in mongo

Comment: In mongo what? Shell? C# Driver? Java Driver? For shell I'd just set a varible for "start" time via `new Date()` or `Date.now` and then another for "end" after the query/pipline has executed and then get the difference. On a local connection that should be a reasonable "guide" without many other factors. Also be sure to run each operation several times and discount the initial runs in order to allow loading of data.

Comment: @BlakesSeven wouldn't running `explain()` be a better solution here if you want raw performance from the database and execution time?

Comment: The timing of explain is the timing of the explain query, not of the query it is explaining. I would imagine find().limit() is faster since it loads less c++ code

Comment: @ThrowsException What Sammaye said, basically. "explain" in an aggregation pipeline only explains the "query" or `$match`, and much because it uses the same mechanism. Therefore it cannot have access to other pipeline stages or timings since it is basically using the same code. And normal queries don't do those other things. Neither is the "limit" explained within a normal query explain, if you get my meaning. Thus "total execution" is the only real timing. The rest is "bunk".

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use query profiling http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: @Sammaye Does not provide accurate profiling on aggregation pipelines as the hooks fire in places for much the same reasons as I already elaborated upon. But I would say that your "guess" should be mostly correct, as `.aggregate()` will likely have more "setup" overhead than `.find()`. But in the particular "example" case here, that difference will very likely be too small to measure in itself. We're talking nanoseconds here on the operation proposed.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways you can get the execution time and performance from queries. First you can set your `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` which will log all database activity to the log with how long each operation took. You can also get performance of your queries from the shell by running `explain()` on the cursor to see what the database is actually doing.

`db.foo.find({}).limit(10).explain()`

you can also do explains for aggregation but it doesn't appear to give you execution time, just the steps it took, so you may have to do

```
var date = new Date()
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$limit: 10}])
var time = new Date() - date;
```

And the aggregation explain if you're interested

`db.foo.aggregate([{$limit: 10}], {explain: true})`

Comment: As I said in my comment, explain timing of the explain query, not of the query it is explaining as such this won't work.

Comment: It would give you the best estimate of the query plan that mongodb is performing in the execution status wouldn't it?

Comment: It would but it would not tell you which is faster

Comment: In this case aggregation vs query no, but OP also asked for a practical way to evaluate query performance. Using explain gives apples to apples comparison without bringing in driver or relying on stopwatches or timers.

Comment: "MongoDB, wich is faster: find.limit(10) or aggregate({$limit:10})"

Comment: I believe the only right answer here is the query profiler: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/profile/